# Человек с большой буквы

Tags: русская-графика

Подскажите, будьте добры, стоит ли писать в данном случае заглавную букву: он был Человеком с большой буквы

Answer (score 2):

Пишут по-разному — и с строчной, и с прописной. См. [**примеры**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh96WC2-7jAhWEAhAIHXJbBn4Q_AUIFygB&biw=1250&bih=600).

**"Русский орфографический словарь"** рекомендует написание с прописной:

[***Человек с большой буквы.***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B&all=x)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос № 202660

Скажите, пожалуйста, в таких выражениях, как "настоящий человек, **(Ч)человек с большой буквы"**, "настоящий автомобиль, (А)автомобиль с большой буквы", буква, стоящая в скобках, должна быть заглавной или строчной? Спасибо.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

С большой буквы пишутся слова **в особом стилистическом употреблении**. Решение о написании слов с большой буквы в этом случае принимает **автор текста.**

А что это значит? В особом (высоком) стилистическом употреблении мы рассматриваем единое сочетание ***Человек с большой буквы*** (как бы приравниваем его к имени собственному).

Примеры:

И ему прощаются все его грешки, ибо человек, способный любить по-настоящему, всегда ***Человек с большой буквы***.  [Эльдар Рязанов. Подведенные итоги (2000)]

Юрий Соболев ― ***это человек с большой буквы***. В его характере на первом месте ― юмор, затем ― остроумие, далее ― интеллект, эрудиция и знание всего и вся. Никогда и никого не обманывает. [Григорий Зеленко.  2003]